# secure.check in template is never called

Tags: security, playframework, playframework-1.x

hey i am using play framework 1.2.4 with secure module.

security model is working great. but not in templates
i am placing

```
    #{secure.check 'PROFILE_1'}
    <li #{if what.equals("1")}class="selected"#{/if}><a href="/some-path">link/a></li>
    #{/secure.check}
```

when debugging the `check` moethod in the `controllers.Secutiry` i dont see any check for 'PROFILE_1'

my Application controller is with @With(Secure.class) and the method rendering the HTML secured with  @Check("ALL_PROFILES")

i thing i am missing something simple

can u help me.

Answer (score 0):

i made changes to the Secure class. cause its a facebook application with different kind of trouble and i guess i mass something there

thank you and sorry